# Use multiple MAX() and MIN() in a query, or am I using >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY wrong?

Tags: php, sql

Can I use multiple MAX() and MIN() in a query? Or am I doing something else wrong in my code?
I get the wrong results...

The code below gives me for t1 MAX 9.63 and MIN 10.00 in temperature.

9.63 is found at 2022-02-09 15:21:29
10 min before, it was 9.06, and 10 after it was 10.38
So, 9.63 is not a MAX nor a MIN number

10.0 is found at 2022-02-09 12:40:09 with higher and lower temps over and under.

```
//-----Get Max and Min------

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT 
MIN(t1) AS t1min, MAX(t1) AS t1max , 
MIN(t2) AS t2min, MAX(t2) AS t2max , 
MIN(t3) AS t3min, MAX(t3) AS t3max , 
MIN(t4) AS t4min, MAX(t4) AS t4max , 
MIN(t5) AS t5min, MAX(t5) AS t5max  
FROM ".$idpass." WHERE logdate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY";  //Where i get $idpass = ($idpass <> "") ? $idpass : "Buapas"; 
//Tried CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY";
//Tried NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY";


$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   // output data of each row
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())    {

   $lastlogdate= $row['logdate'] ;
   $T1min= $row['t1min'] ;
   $T2min= $row['t2min'] ;
   $T3min= $row['t3min'] ;
   $T4min= $row['t4min'] ;
   $T5min= $row['t5min'] ;
   $T1max= $row['t1max'] ;
   $T2max= $row['t2max'] ;
   $T3max= $row['t3max'] ;
   $T4max= $row['t4max'] ;
   $T5max= $row['t5max'] ;
                                           }
                           } else {
   echo "0 results hentet fra databasen";
                                   }
$conn->close();
```

If i remove the

```
, MAX(t1) AS t1max , 
MIN(t2) AS t2min, MAX(t2) AS t2max , 
MIN(t3) AS t3min, MAX(t3) AS t3max , 
MIN(t4) AS t4min, MAX(t4) AS t4max , 
MIN(t5) AS t5min, MAX(t5) AS t5max
```

from my code, it still says 10.0 in the MIN t1

Comment: What type is logdate? If it is a string, you can get strange results. If it is a timestamp, you might have time-zone issues. You are storing your timestamps as UTC?

Comment: Also are t1-t5 columns numbers? Or are they strings?

Comment: t1 to t5 are collums from the databse containing tempratures formated: 5.63.

Comment: logdate is indeed a date collum with format: 2022-02-09 13:10:22

Comment: My only guess is your columns are strings. 1 < 9 which means 10 < 9 in strings.
MAX('9.63' , '10.0') is therefor 9.63 Can't think about anything else.

Comment: @VincentNikkelen I did have the variables declared as $T1=""; at the start of the PHP. Have removed it now, and will see if i get another results without. At first glance, it looks like it solved the problem.

Comment: I had the SQL collum set to varchar 50, changed it to Desimal 5,2 and it solved the problem. Now i just need to solve how to use desimal 5,2 in empty collums...

Comment: Little tip: If you don't need exact precision, don't use Decimal(5,2). Imagine you build a big application and then suddenly you get your data in with 3 digits.
Only use Decimal when you must have exact precision. E.g. when working with money.

Comment: But what should I use? @vincent

Comment: That is up to you to decide. It isn't wrong to use Decimal(), just be aware of the limitation. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-types.html for more info on data types.

Answer (score 0):

When you define your columns as strings, sorting behaves different then you'd expect.

In strings, '10' < '9' as '1' < '9'. (first character is compared, then the secend etc.) This means that MAX('9.63' , '10.0') is '9.63' as 9 is larger than 1.

Change to a different data-type, and you are good to go.

Use for example Decimal(5,2) when you need precision and not more than two decimals. Use float is you can accept small rounding errors but need more digits.

More on data-types: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-types.html